Dynamic Import — Prisma
My code is currently like this because I'm developing a project that I need to have ready as soon as possible.
import * as PrismaClient from '@prisma/client'
import { Prisma } from '../lib/prisma'

/**
 * Prisma types
 */

export type TPrisma = typeof Prisma
export type TModelNames = Prisma.ModelName

/**
 * Prisma columns by model
 */

type TUsersColumns = PrismaClient.Prisma.UsersScalarFieldEnum
type TSessionColumns = PrismaClient.Prisma.SessionsScalarFieldEnum

type TTeamsColumns = PrismaClient.Prisma.TeamsScalarFieldEnum
type TTeamMembersColumns = PrismaClient.Prisma.Team_membersScalarFieldEnum

type TValuesColumns = PrismaClient.Prisma.ValuesScalarFieldEnum
type TCategoriesColumns = PrismaClient.Prisma.CategoriesScalarFieldEnum
type TTransactionsColumns = PrismaClient.Prisma.TransactionsScalarFieldEnum

export type TColumns<T extends TModelNames> = T extends 'users'
  ? TUsersColumns
  : T extends 'sessions'
  ? TSessionColumns
  : T extends 'teams' 
  ? TTeamsColumns
  : T extends 'team_members'
  ? TTeamMembersColumns
  : T extends 'values'
  ? TValuesColumns
  : T extends 'categories'
  ? TCategoriesColumns
  : T extends 'transactions'
  ? TTransactionsColumns
  : never

Unfortunately, I can't do it and I don't have time to get stuck in this code any longer.
I would be very grateful if you could help me.
But I'd really like to know how to dynamically import the column types of each model I have in my Prisma schema.

Hi, please read how to ask. As is, it doesn't fit on this site...
